# How to add a relative url link to a page from a Link button on a web part SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, navigation

It may be a silly question but still I would like to know. I have page under site pages, a web part on that page, and a link button on the web part. I want to navigate to another page under site pages from that link button on the web part. What should be the relative URL to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx");
```

Or

```
Response.Redirect("/SiteCollection/Site/SitePages/PageName.aspx");
```

Comment: I want to avoid Site Collection and site name.

Comment: Please try the first one then !

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Indeed Response.Redirect works but I am curious to know is it poosible by setting the page URL in HTML or PostBackURL.

Comment: Didn't got you. The Relative URL is simple i;e "PageName.aspx". Just use this, a simple anchor tag will also work like <a href="PageName.aspx"/>

Comment: Simple page name doesn't work. It tries to look for the page at Site Collection Level. Not under Site Pages.

Comment: are you using forward slash("/") also? Please exclude any slash and just the name of the page.

Comment: Writing just page name only. It tries to navigate to http://<servername>/_controlTemplates/<SiteName>/Page.aspx

Comment: OK, if this is the issue, i recommend you to use a bit JavaScript. Get the url and the SubString and append the PageName in the link button.